# Добавление данных в таблицу MySQL с использованием С#

Tags: c#, mysql

Не работает запрос добавления данных в таблицу. Запрос рабочий, спокойно работает в workbanch'e, однако на данный код таблица не реагирует. Что не так?

```
string connstr = "server=localhost; user=root; database=users_db; password=0000";
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connstr);
string sql_registrUser = "INSERT INTO `users_db`.`users` (`user_login`, `user_password`) VALUES ('" + login + "', '" + password + "');";
MySqlCommand comm_registr = new MySqlCommand(sql_registrUser, conn);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно пишут примерно такое (пример для OLEDB, но сути это не меняет)

```
private OleDbConnection GetConnection()
    {
        OleDbConnectionStringBuilder oleStringBuilder = new OleDbConnectionStringBuilder();
        oleStringBuilder.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0";

        var currentDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(this.GetType().Assembly.Location);
        oleStringBuilder.DataSource = Path.Combine(currentDir, "wordsDb.accdb");

        OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(oleStringBuilder.ConnectionString);

        return connection;
    }
```

тогда для Insert будет так

```
public int AddWord(Word word)
    {
        if (word == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(word));
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(word.Eng)) throw new ArgumentException("Английское значение обязательное");
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(word.Rus)) throw new ArgumentException("Русское значение обязательное");

        int result = 0;

        using (OleDbConnection connection = GetConnection())
        using (OleDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Words (english, russian) VALUES (@eng, @rus)";
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("eng", word.Eng);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("rus", word.Rus);

            connection.Open();
            result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался. Для добавления записи в таблицу необходимо использовать:

```
MyCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Тогда мой код преобразуется в следующий:

```
string connstr = "server=localhost; user=root; database=users_db; password=0000";
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connstr))
   {
       conn.Open();
       string sql_registrUser = "INSERT INTO `users_db`.`users` (`user_login`, `user_password`) VALUES ('" + login + "', '" + password + "');";
       MySqlCommand comm_registr = new MySqlCommand(sql_registrUser, conn);
       comm_registr.ExecuteNonQuery();
       conn.Close();
   }
```

Comment: Еще надо бы открыть соединение, перед тем как... Да, и не хило бы, все работу с соединением обернуть в `using`

Comment: Да, спасибо за замечание. Сейчас поправлю.